# How to remove an attribute from the edge label in a networkx graph?

Tags: python, networkx

How to remove an attribute from the edge label in a networkx graph?

The following example

```
edgelabels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G, 'weight')

nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, label_pos=0.5, alpha=0.5, edge_color='k')
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, labels = edgelabels)
```

prints {'weight': n} on each edge label: what I want is 'n' alone. This would make the graph far more legible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to draw just the number for a 'weight' attribute.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edge(1,2,weight=7)
G.add_edge(2,3,weight=42)
labels = {}
for u,v,data in G.edges(data=True):
    labels[(u,v)] = data['weight']

pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw(G,pos)
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, edge_labels=labels)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have 'n' as an edge label, you must use the parameter 'edge_labels' with draw_networkx_edge_labels, instead of 'labels'.

```
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, edge_labels = edgelabels)
```